# SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number error

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

Column definition in both source and target table is `VARCHAR2(40)` but it gives

> SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number error while inserting records`.

```
Source table: 
DESC I002BDS_FILTER_ITEM_W
Name            Null Type           
--------------- ---- --------------         
EVAL_VALUE           VARCHAR2(40)   

Target table
DESC FILTER_ITEM_W
Name            Null Type           
--------------- ---- --------------         
EVAL_VALUE           VARCHAR2(40)
```

**Source table values:**

[image]

**INSERT statement:**

```
INSERT
       /*+ APPEND  */
INTO
    HYU_ODI_WORK_6.FILTER_ITEM_W T
    (
        EVAL_VALUE
    )
SELECT
    EVAL_VALUE
FROM
    I002BDS_FILTER_ITEM_W;
```

Please Help!

Comment: Is the value for "SELECT EVAL_VALUE FROM I002BDS_FILTER_ITEM_W" not exceeding the limits of filter_item_w OR is it not NULL?  Maybe do a min / max of EVAL_VALUE .

Comment: What is the complete error stack you get from the insert? I would guess you either have a virtual column on the target table you haven't shown, or a function-based index, or perhaps more likely a trigger; and whichever one of those you have is trying to convert part of the string into a number. The full error should tell you exactly what is throwing that exception.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks buddy..... I have checked in the database and one index in working on target table column, which converts column values into number type.

Comment: @SQLPLSQL - ok, so have you fixed the issue now?

Comment: @AlexPoole .... Yes.... Thanks